# Insufficient money, need xxxxxx Satoshis

Tags: satoshi

Trying to process a transaction out of my **Multibit wallet**, entering the key & the error message **'insufficient money'** appears on the screen. I know that I need to add a transaction fee, which I am doing, however the number of Satoshis required increases at every attempt! For instance, the transaction will require **100250 Satoshis**, so I will amend the amount being transferred to 100300 to compensate & allow for any fluctuation.

The warning then reappears stating it now requires 100500 Satoshis.
This cycle is continuing, I can't find a figure beg enough to get
ahead of the curve, without literally throwing my money away! Any help
would be appreciated, this has been frustrating me for some time now!

Answer (score 1):

Seems others have had similar problems with that wallet

> they say the fee is like 0.0001 BTC but I had to make it 0.0005 or more BTC for it to send.

- [Support](https://multibit.org/help/hd0.4/contents.html)
- [Issue](https://github.com/Multibit-Legacy/multibit-hd/issues/862)